# ASP.Net 4.0 AutoStart feature with Mod_Mono

Tags: asp.net, mono, apache2, mod-mono

Does anybody knows whether Mono (Mod_Mono) supports the new ASP.Net 4.0 feature called AutoStart?

If it supports, how can I configure Apache2/mod_mono to enable it?

If it doesn't, is an automated script to make a request on every restart of apache2 service the best way to go?

I have searched on the internet but couldn't find anything about Mono supporting the AutoStart (pre-warm) feature.

This feature is discussed in the following links:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/01/31/asp-net-4-0-how-to-use-application-warm-up-class.aspx

Thanks!

Comment: You should first learn Apache. If it does not have a concept like application pool, then auto-start is not applicable at all.

Comment: Yes, I know. But since the Warm Up module is an IIS module and since Apache does support modules, I thought that maybe someone could point me in the right direction. Besides, warm-up sites is a very common necessity and it would be odd if Apache doesn't support it at all.

Comment: Did you ever find out if this was available in Mod_Mono?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, never. I just got downvoted for even asking...